# I can't access Sublime Text 3 to commit in Git Bash (Windows 10)

Tags: git, bash, github, sublimetext3

I'm doing the Udacity course on Github and I'm trying to setup Sublime Text 3 with Github.

Running the "subl" command works and the text editor runs normally but when I try to commit something, which brings along Sublime to type the comment for the commit, I get this error.

C:/Program Files/Git/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: C:/Program: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:/Program Files/Git/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'.

I've tried adding the Sublime installation directory to my Windows PATH, and trying to create the directory specified in the error message.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using the mintty emulator by the way,.

Comment: That's a quoting issue it looks like. The path is getting word-split by the shell. How did you set up sublime text for this? Did you follow the class's directions **exactly**?

Comment: Oops, apparently my short attention span has led me to forget two  bash commands to input before I can use Sublime to commit!

Answer (score 0):

Oops, turns out the problem is my fault. There were some commands I forgot to run in the git bash command line.
For reference, the commands are:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

and

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: Neither of those commands has anything to do with commit message editing. The first controls what `git push` does when no other arguments are given (see the entry on [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)) and the second controls the style git uses to write out merge conflicts (see [git-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)). So this is *very* unlikely to have affected the original issue.